# MLlib: For offline training, Storm: to use (deploy) model learned

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, apache-spark-mllib

It is possible to train a model with MLlib and use it in a Storm topology?
I get a set of inputs from users and plan to give a recommendation.

Comment: You can use Spark Streaming..

Comment: Thank you @imagin. I know Spark Streaming. But I was wondering if it is possible to deploy in Storm. There are advantages. In this case I do not intend to use the state.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark MLLib to save the model as PMML. [model.toPMML()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-pmml-model-export.html)

And use this PMML in Storm to do the prediction. [Storm Extension for PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-storm)

Comment: Thanks. But not supports multiclassification and Colobarative filtering. No there a way to serialize ? or export the mathematical formula?

Comment: @RookieSpark what do you mean ? This solution sounds viable !

Comment: The PMML Model in spark MLlib only support this algorithms https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-pmml-model-export.html

Comment: The ideia is create a recommendation systems (offline learning).  Any suggestions? Storm + MLLib or Spark Streaming + MLIB. The latency is a very important factor

Comment: We have successfully used and scaled spark streaming in production using the model built by MLLib.